# Printing Colored Characters in Lisp / Emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp

I'm writing a simple connect-4 program in Lisp and ideally each player (red, black) would have their own color when the game state is displayed. Does anyone know how to print colored ASCII characters? How is this done in general? I'm using emacs 23, so the solution might be specific to emacs itself.

Anyways, I've checked the hyperspec to see if FORMAT can do it but no luck so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what Lisp? Emacs Lisp? The 'HyperSpec' is not for Emacs Lisp, but Common Lisp. Printing colored text from Emacs Lisp should be covered in the Emacs manual. Common Lisp has no built-in facilities for colored text, because the user interface is outside the scope of the Common Lisp standard. Typically one would use a graphical toolkit (like CAPI, CLIM, ...) or something like a 'curses' interface. If you are using Emacs Lisp, then you can use Emacs built-in functionality. I guess you could also look at some of the games that are coming with Emacs for inspiration.

Comment: It is possible that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code is the simple solution you are looking for, depending on what you mean by "Lisp" as Rainer commented.

Comment: I'm using SBCL which is one of the many flavors of CL, although it's running on SLIME in emacs. This should be covered by the emacs manual though, right? 

Thanks for the input, my world of lisp broadens daily.

Comment: You have two very different choices: you can write the game in SBCL, in which case you'll need a Common Lisp user interface library, or you can write it in Emacs Lisp and use Emacs' built-in functionality.

SLIME is what you use to *edit* Common Lisp code in emacs - like a text editor but with many more features. Your Lisp code is not *running* in Emacs. If you want code to run in Emacs (and use Emacs' built-in color text ability), it'll have to be Emacs Lisp. You'll need to decide which way you want to do things before you can solve this problem.

Comment: did you find the solution you were looking for?

Answer (score 6):

The appearance of text in Emacs is controlled by *faces*.  Face can be changed through either *overlay* or *text properties*.  Here is an example using the latter:

```
;; Emacs-Lisp
(insert (propertize "foo" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red")))
```

However, if the game is implemented in SBCL, you'll need a way to communicate with Emacs from your SBCL program.  As it seems that you're using Slime, using Swank, which is a part of Slime, might be the most convenient:

```
;; Common-Lisp
(swank::eval-in-emacs
 '(with-current-buffer (slime-repl-buffer)
    (insert (propertize "foo" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red")))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Shameless self plug: you might want to try [this](http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/gtfl/), which is a graphical terminal for Common Lisp running in a web browser. It uses html for printing stuff, so you could do something like:

```
(gtfl-out (:p :style "color:red;" "some characters"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote an Elisp defun to test the colors. It could be useful for example when setting up the general colors of the Linux VTs. Note that the color list ("black", "red", etc.) is only how it is conventionally and usually defined - if you set them up as other colors, perhaps red won't be red anymore. Still, it can be useful to test.

```
;;;; insert colored and/or bright text
(defun insert-colored-text (str clr bright)
  "Inserts str at point, in color clr, bright or not."
  (interactive (list (read-string " String: ")
                     (read-string " Color: ")
                     (y-or-n-p    " Bright? ") ))
  (insert (propertize str 'font-lock-face
          `(:weight ,(if bright 'bold 'normal) :foreground ,clr) )))
(defalias 'ict 'insert-colored-text)

(defun test-all-faces ()
  "Prints a test string in al colors, both normal and bright."
  (interactive)
  (let ((str "This is what it looks like"))
    (dolist (bold '(nil t) nil)
      (dolist (color
               '("black" "red" "green" "yellow" "blue"
                 "magenta" "cyan" "white") nil)
        (insert-colored-text
         (format "%s in %s (that is %sbold)\n" str color
                 (if bold "" "not ")) color bold) ))))
(defalias 'taf 'test-all-faces)
```

[example output http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/cols.png](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/cols.png)

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for the same answer and been here, and after a while found the answer from another link[[Change the color of the text in the Common Lisp REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208933/change-the-color-of-the-text-in-the-common-lisp-repl]).

I think maybe you need it,the answer is:

> Blockquote

You can use ANSI escape code to print colorful texts:

(format t "~c[31mabc~c[0m~%" #\ESC #\ESC) ; this prints a red "abc" for most modern terminals
I'm not sure whether this works in slime, although.

shareimprove this answer
answered Oct 6 '13 at 16:06

SaltyEgg
626412

> Blockquote

Comment: **Thank You** This post lead me to a deeper understanding of how the format function works! Do you know where the #\ESC function is documented?

Comment: #\ESC is not in the standard, a more portable expression might be `(format t "~c[31mRed~:*~c[32mGreen~:*~c[34mBlue~:*~c[mPlain~%" (code-char 27))`